# Insert into hive partitioned table SemanticException

Tags: hadoop, hive

First I create a hive partitioned table:

```
hive> create table partition_table
    > (sid int ,sname string ,age int)            
    > partitioned by (sex string)     
    > row format delimited fields terminated by',';  
OK
Time taken: 1.232 seconds
```

The table desc is given below:

```
 hive> desc partition_table;
    OK
    sid                     int                                         
    sname                   string                                      
    age                     int                                         
    sex                     string                                      

# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment             

sex                     string                                      
Time taken: 0.34 seconds, Fetched: 9 row(s)
```

and then I insert some data into this table but it doesn't work.

```
hive> insert into table partition_table partition(sex='M')select sno ,sname ,age from student1 where sex ='M';
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10006]: Line 1:44 Partition not found ''M''
```

To avoid this I wrote the following command and then executed my insert command, even then I get the same error repeatedly.

```
set exec.dynamic.partition=true;                                                                           
set exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

Comment: can you add `select sno ,sname ,age from student1 where sex ='M'` output to question. there is no issue with query.

Comment: of course  ..   does  the partition  column  must be  English

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add the partition before loading:

```
ALTER TABLE partition_table ADD PARTITION( sex= 'M' );
insert into table partition_table partition(sex='M') select sno ,sname ,age from student1 where sex ='M';
```

or try dynamic partitioning:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE partition_table PARTITION (sex)
SELECT sid, sname, age, sex
FROM student1;
```

Comment: adding partition is unnecessary . Query does it automatically.

Comment: You can see his error says it's not finding partition 'M'.  In my second solution you can see I recommended dynamic partitioning.  Did you stop reading at line four?

Comment: your answer is very useful  but when I  try ` ALTER TABLE partition_table ADD PARTITION( sex= 'xxx' );  ` --  it caused a new error   `FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)
`    but I have already  set the  `hive-site.xml `   < property>
 < name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL< /name>
 < value>jdbc:mysql://djt01:3306/hive?characterEncoding=UTF-8< /value>
 < description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore< /description>
< /property>

Comment: I  search this error  it  might be a character setting  problem

Comment: does  the partition  column  must be  English . I use  other language